# How to update a logo on a Company page on Stack Overflow developer story pages?

Tags: support, status-deferred, developer-story

My Developer Story on Stack Overflow displays the old logo of my current employer.

It says at the bottom of the Developer Story page that company information is provided by CrunchBase. However, when I visit CrunchBase, it displays the correct, up-to-date image.

Who manages Company pages on Stack Overflow? Should I seek an administrator within my organisation or is this information somehow managed by the community?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Company Pages are managed by companies. Stack Overflow does not manage the content (including logos) on a Company Page. Unfortunately at this time the only way you can suggest updating a logo is by reaching out to the person who manages your company's Company Page.